# Disable the listener to src of iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, iframe, angularjs-watch

I have an iframe in my template, `src` refers to a physical html file.

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="{{src}}">
</iframe>
```

In the controller, a function `rewriteAllFiles` is called from time to time to update the physical `html, js, css` files. It first removes all the old files, then write the new one, then refresh the iframe.

```
var refreshIframe = function () {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');
    iframe.src = iframe.src;
    console.log("refreshIframe, done")
}

rewriteAllFiles = function (path, files) {
    return $http.post('/emptyDir', { dir: prefix + idP + "/", path: path })
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log("rewriteAllFiles /emptyDir, done");
            return $http.post('/writeFiles', { dir: prefix + idP + "/", files: files })
                .then(function (res) {
                    console.log("rewriteAllFiles /writeFiles, done");
                    refreshIframe();
                    return res
                })
        })
}

$scope.$watch(... {
    return rewriteAllFiles($location.path(), $scope.files);
})
```

My test shows sometimes it works without error, but sometimes, it gives the following log:

```
rewriteAllFiles /emptyDir, done
GET http://localhost:3000/tmp/P0L7JSEOWux3YE1FAAA6/index.html 404 (Not Found)
rewriteAllFiles /writeFiles, done
refreshIframe, done
```

So it seems that after the old files are removed and before new files are written, the html template tries to load `src`, and of cause the file is temporarily unavailable. I did not set a watcher for `src`, does anyone know where is the listener to `src`, and how to disable it?

**Edit 1:** here is the code of `writeFiles` in the server side:

```
router.post('/writeFiles', function (req, res, next) {
    var dir = req.body.dir, files = req.body.files;
    var fs = require('fs');
    var queue = files.map(function (file) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            fs.writeFile(dir + file.name, file.body, function (err) {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                console.log(dir + file.name + " is written");
                resolve(file);
            })
        })
    });

    Promise.all(queue)
        .then(function(files) {
            console.log("All files have been successfully written");
            res.json(dir);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            return console.log(err)
        });
});
```

Comment: Should use `ng-src`. Sounds like post request is completing before files are written so problem is server side

Comment: I tried `<iframe id="myiframe" ng-src="{{src}}">`, but it still gives Not Found error... Could you elaborate more about `post request is completing...`?

Comment: I am suggesting that your server code logic is sending a response before the files have been written.

Comment: I just added the code of `writeFiles` on the server side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise that it is related to another line of code in the controller.

```
$scope.src = getSrc() // getSrc(); returns the right html link initiated by a resolving 

$scope.$watch(... {
    return rewriteAllFiles($location.path(), $scope.files);
})
```

When we load the template, the above code has a possibility that `$scope.src = getSrc()` is executed just after after the old files are removed and before new files are written, which raises a `Not Found` error.

So we just need to make sure the execution order by `then`; the following code works:

```
$scope.$watch(... {
    return rewriteAllFiles($location.path(), $scope.files)
        .then(function () {
            $scope.src = getSrcP();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try {{::src}}. It just be rendered once.

Comment: I tried `<iframe id="myiframe" src="{{::src}}">` and `<iframe id="myiframe" src={{::src}}>`, it still gives an error.